# Unit tests fail in randomly in mocha/chai JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am currently testing my Express app and I decided to go with **Mocha/Chai/Chai-Http**.
i set my tests and most of the times the tests **pass** but **randomly** sometimes some tests **fail**
there is no pattern !!

here's the code :

```js
describe("projectTest :>> login", () => {
  // Create a user in order to have the  access token  to execute authenticated API
  before(function (done) {
    let person = new User({
      email: "dev.test@test.com",
      password: "<hashed password>",
      firstName: "dev",
      lastName: "test",
      jobPosition: "Web Developer",
    });
    person.save();

    done();
  });

  /*
   * Test the /POST login route
   */
  describe(" projectTest :>> /POST login ", () => {
    it("it should success if credential (person) is valid ", done => {
      chai
        .request(server)
        .post("/api/projectTest/account/login")
        .send({
          email: "dev.test@test.com",
          password: "<password>",
        })
        .end(function (error, response) {
          if (error) done(error);

          response.should.have.status(200);
          response.body.should.have.property("token");
          done();
        });
    });
  });

  after(function () {
    User.deleteMany({}, function () {});
  });
});
```

i run it with the following mocha line
`$ cross-env NODE_ENV=test PROJECT_NAME=projectTest mocha --timeout 20000 ./routes/projectTest/**/*.spec.js --exit`

this is the error message :

`Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 400`

I m using `chai 4.2.0` , `mocha 10.0.0` and `chai-http 4.3.0`

Comment: what is the endpoint you are trying to test, maybe its returning something unexpected

Comment: i did't change the body of post method 
instead i m getting this error sometimes 
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 400

Comment: It's not very useful to see the code of the test when it's the endpoint that seems to be failing unexpectedly.

Comment: need to see the endpoint to help, code for test lgtm

Comment: You should be able to dump the the response body to see the underlying Express error.

Comment: i edited the question please take look at the updates !

Comment: @YashKumarVerma sometimes it returns codeStatus 400,401 and 200 and expected 200

Comment: is any field unique that can cause this?

Comment: can you give more details please